# php - echo to return results with curly and square brackets

Tags: php, json

i have a script that returns the json results in this

Figure 1

```
["No=>0001","Name=>DONALD FRIMP","Address=>B BLOCK 2"]
```

but i want it to return like this

Figure 2

```
[{"No":"0001","Address":"B BLOCK 2"}]
```

this is my php

```
$data=array('No=>'.$customer->No,Address=>'.$customer->Address);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Any help on how to get json to return like `figure 2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$data=array('No'=>$customer->No,'Address'=>$customer->Address);
echo json_encode(array($data));
```

Comment: using above code i am getting `[{"No":"some value","Address":"som value"}]`

Comment: and in console.log I am getting `Array(1)
0
:
Object
Address
:
"som value"
No
:
"some value"
__proto__
:
Object
length
:
1`

Answer (score 1):

Use a proper array:

```
$data=array('No' => $customer->No, 'Address' => $customer->Address);
echo json_encode($data);
```

That will output a JSON object. If you want it wrapped in a list in JSON, wrap it in an array in PHP:

```
echo json_encode(array($data));
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use an array

```
$myArray[]['No'] = "0001";
$myArray[]['Address'] = "B BLOCK 2";

echo json_encode($myArray);
```